# Why do multiple windows of some applications share same pid?

Tags: linux, operating-system, multiple-instances

Two windows of 'mousepad' (executed by different terminals), for instance, share same pid. There is only one entry in "ps -e | grep mousepad" and "wmctrl -p -l" indicates that the two windows have same pid. I am trying to create an application which is based on 'pid' and multiple windows of the same application must have different pid. Is there a way to force application to create new instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do multiple windows of some applications share same pid?

Many programs - not only under Linux but also under Windows - first check if the program is already started.

If yes, the new instance of the program sends some information to the already running instance telling that instance that a new window shall be opened.

Then the new instance is exiting.

This means that only one instance (the one that has been started first) is running.

> Is there a way to force application to create new instance?

Some programs (like Microsoft Office under Windows) have the possibility to disable this behaviour in the program's settings.

Unfortunately, I don't know about "mousepad".

However, there seems to be no possibility to do this independently of the specific program. (... if the program does not have such a setting.)

Maybe it is possible to find out how a program detects if another instance is already running and to "block" this detection somehow...